# Nested list can not be packed?

Tags: packed-arrays

Why can't nested list be packed?

```
In[252]:= ftest = {1., {3.}};
ftest = Developer`ToPackedArray[ftest];
Developer`PackedArrayQ[ftest]
```

> Out[254]= False

Comment: Only tensors (passes `ArrayQ[]`) can be packed. `{{1.}, {3.}}`, `{{1., 3.}}`, and `{1., 3.}` can all be packed, but yours can't.

Comment: Thanks! I guess it has something to do how memory can be allocated.

Comment: (P.S. could anyone who can link to the appropriate place in the docs answer this question for me? I promise to upvote. ;))

Comment: @J.M. _"Packed arrays are a representation for rectangular tensors of machine integers, machine reals, and complex numbers with real and imaginary parts that are machine reals." http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LinearAlgebraPerformance.html

Comment: Just think about how you would implement such a data structure in a low-level language like C.  It's much more complicated than dealing with a rectangular array.  For a rectangular array you only need to store its data and its dimensions, and indexing into it is trivial.  That's what "packed" means here: use one flat block of memory, which is very fast.  For a ragged 2D array you'd likely have multiple 1D sub-arrays allocated separately and a pointer vector with references to each.  Each sub-array needs to store its length separately.  This is exactly what a *non-packed* list is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per J.M.'s and Dr. Belisarius's comment:

Only tensors passing `ArrayQ` can be packed. Any of `{{1.}, {3.}}, {{1., 3.}}`, and `{1., 3.}` can be packed, but ragged, non-rectangular lists (e.g. `{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}}` or `{1, {2}, 3}`) cannot.

> "Packed arrays are a representation for rectangular tensors of machine integers, machine reals, and complex numbers with real and imaginary parts that are machine reals"

```
lists = N@{
    {{1}, {3}},
    {{1, 3}},
    {1, 3},
    {1},
    {1, 2},
    {1, {2}, 3},
    {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}}
    };
ArrayQ /@ lists
packed = Developer`ToPackedArray /@ lists;
Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ packed
```

> ```
> {True, True, True, True, True, False, False} (* ArrayQ *)
>
> {True, True, True, True, True, False, False} (* PackedArrayQ *)
> ```

from the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LinearAlgebraPerformance.html).